# unknown error parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database

Here is the error:

```
undefined:1
{
^
```

Im using Node.js to insert a Json file into a database.

This is the function that i use to read a file that looks like

```
fs.readFile("json.json", function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log("couldn't read file");
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

json.json:

```
{
    elements:[
        {
        "angle":90,
        "x":80,
        "y":50,
        "width":100,
        "heigth":150,
        "type":"rectangle"
        settings:{
            "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        {
        "angle":90,
        "x":80,
        "y":50,
        "width":100,
        "heigth":150,
        "type":"rectangle"
        settings:{
            "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want to insert the Json into my database,

my database elements table looks something like:

```
elements:
element_id
page_id
x
y
width
height
type
```

i  haven't figured out how im gonna do the settings but first i need to get the data in the database.Can someone help me.

Comment: Which database? What are you using to connect to it?

Comment: In the title you say you are getting an error. Please write what error, and where it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were some mistakes in your JS code and in JSON file,  corrected  and below is the working copy

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./json.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log("couldn't read file");
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
});



{
    "elements":[
        {
        "angle":90,
        "x":80,
        "y":50,
        "width":100,
        "heigth":150,
        "type":"rectangle",
        "settings":{
                "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
            }
        },
        {
        "angle":90,
        "x":80,
        "y":50,
        "width":100,
        "heigth":150,
        "type":"rectangle",
        "settings":{
                "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: oh wow thanks,  but im still getting an error:


undefined:1
{
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at c:\Program Files\Git\TestSomeNodejs\DataBaseConnection.js:24:22
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)

that on the console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
                                                ^

Comment: i gave a working copy for the `read a json and and parse it` , based on the data and code you provided. which i tested on my local node and its working. is that part working for you, with my changes ?  i mean, if you exclude the DB part

Comment: Your code works thanks. there is a screenshot of the json + error: http://puu.sh/nclr5/a00d12952d.png

Comment: Looks like, the json in the image is different from the json you provided, there might be some mistake in the json.  by the way it is always better todo JSON.parse inside a try-catch

Comment: If i run i throu a json validator it tells me "Valid JSON"?

Comment: The JSON is different but there both valid as of http://jsonlint.com/
but i still get the error at the first { <-- first character in the file